# Dynamically creating a dictionary

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have a said class given below:

```
 public class ABC : XYZ
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing this class into another class as:

```
    public class otherClass : someClass, someInterface
   {
        private readonly ABC _ABC;


     public PythonRunner(ILogger<com> logger, ABC ABC)
            : base(logger, acpApiService, apxApiService, logAttributes, mapper)
     {
         ABC = ABC;
            
        }
    Public Void SomeFunc()
    { Console.WriteLine(_ABC.username)
       Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       dic.Add("username", _ABC.Username);
       dic.Add("password", _ABC.Password);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically do this? What I mean is I don't want to keep stating the `dic.Add("password", _ABC.Password);` for each key-value pair I want to enter in the dictionary. There are multiple records and I'd like to loop through them, if there is a way. I am also quite new to C# so please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make some corrections to run, but you can do it using the code below.  I'm using .NET 6 but it will run for previous versions.

```
foreach(var prop in _ABC.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            _dic.Add(prop.Name, _ABC.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(_ABC, null).ToString());
        }
```

Example:

```
var user = new UserModel()
{
  Username = "Someone",
  Password = "SafePassword"
};

var other = new OtherClass(user);
other.PrintDictonary();

public class UserModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    private readonly UserModel _ABC;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public OtherClass(UserModel ABC)
    {
         _ABC = ABC;    
         SomeFunc();        
    }
    public void SomeFunc()
    {       
        foreach(var prop in _ABC.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            _dic.Add(prop.Name, _ABC.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(_ABC, null).ToString());
        }       
    }

    public void PrintDictonary()
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in _dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: { entry.Key } Value { entry.Value }");
        }
    }
}
//It will print in console: 
//Key: Username Value Someone
//Key: Password Value SafePassword
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Is it possible to create a string of key value pairs instead of a dictionary? I know we can convert the dictionary to a string but can it be done without making it a dictionary?

Comment: You can change the declaration of _dic to: private List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(); 
On add: _list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(prop.Name, _ABC.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(_ABC, null).ToString()));
On print: Console.WriteLine(entry);

Comment: Thanks!! One last question is it possible to access a dictionary within a dictionary?  Can you see this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72120856/accessing-key-and-values-of-a-dictionary-within-a-dictionary/72120971#72120971