# Accessing key and values of a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have the following file:

```
{ "Ti": 12,
    "IES": false,
    "End": {
        "ABC": "test1",
        "XYZ": "test2",
        "QWE": "test3"
    }
```

and I have the following C# code that is getting these values through a class:

```
foreach (var prop in _ABC.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            _dic.Add(prop.Name, _ABC.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(_ABC, null).ToString());
        }
```

This does not give me the values/keys of the dictionary within the existing dictionary. The class ABC looks like following:

```
   public class ABC
{
    public string Ti { get; set; }
    public string IES { get; set; }
    public End End { get; set; }
    
}

public class END
{
    public string ABC { get; set; }
    public string XYZ { get; set; }
    public string QWE { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the loop to go further in to access the values of `.END` class

Answer (score 0):

You could try deserializing the contents. It's much more robust and less error prone.

--EDITED--

Change some types:

- `Ti` from `string` to `int`
- `IES` from `string` to `bool`
- `End` from `END` to `Dictionary<string, string>`

---

```
public class ABC
{
    public int Ti { get; set; }
    public bool IES { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> End { get; set; }
}
```

The deserializing code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

//[...]

var fileContent = @"{ ""Ti"": 12,
    ""IES"": false,
    ""End"": {
        ""ABC"": ""test1"",
        ""XYZ"": ""test2"",
        ""QWE"": ""test3""
    }
}";

var abc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ABC>(fileContent);
    
Console.WriteLine($"Ti: {abc.Ti}");
Console.WriteLine($"IES: {abc.IES}");
foreach (var key in abc.End.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"End.{key}: {abc.End[key]}");
}
```

Comment: yeah, but this isn't a scalable approach, is it? What if we add more values like say 50 more, I'd have to manually enter each one of them, right?

Comment: Check it now: I replaced the `END` class with a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, this still will be the same issue, if we add more values that are not in `END`, right? So, let's say we add more values in the first level of the dictionary, we will have to keep manually adding those keys & values.